# What is the difference in usage of [実行]{じっこう}する and [実施]{じっし}する?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

So at my office i see both [実施]{じっし}する and [実行]{じっこう}する used a lot to mean "carry out" a task.

Any time I ask a Japanese person they tell me "they are the same".

Can anyone tell me any differences in usages, or any specific cases where one is preferred over the other? Or any specific nuances one implies?

Some examples straight from my email inbox:

- 以下のコマンドを実行してください。
- バッチの再実行をしました。
- バッチを毎時0分に実施します。
- 忘年会を実施することになりました。
- 結合テストケースを実施します。

Comment: Thank you for this question. I would also add to this line the verb "実現".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an IT context 実行 is execution in the sense of executing a program. 実施, on the other hand, refers generally to putting some plan into action. 実行 and 実施 do have overlapping meanings in the sense that they involve setting something in action, but the IT meaning is exclusive to 実行 in most usage that I've seen (and in the dictionary) though there may be some overlap there.

In broader terms separated from IT, 実行 is something more labored and requiring some sort of judgment or effort beyond that which you would associate with 実施, like "time to execute plan B!" I associate 実施 more with the English meaning of "conduct," as in "conduct an examination/experiment/survey/whatever." It refers simply to a real life implementation of something that is planned but that is not extraordinary in any particular sense.

There's a nice answer here that has a little more discussion about it: http://okwave.jp/qa/q7438350.html

Comment: [ 実施 more with the English meaning of "conduct" ] => make sense and cleared my confusion

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @ssb said, you can often see `実施` in stores, コンビニ, restaurants, etc., when there is something special happening (usually as `実施中`).

> - 電気製品全品30%オフセール**実施中**！　→　All electronics 30% off (Happening now)!
> - JR全国全線カード、夏キャンペーン７/１（月）より**実施**　→　JR Summer Special, (Card for) All lines around the country, starting 7/1
> - お客様にお礼を！飲み放題ドリンクバー、お一人様￥100！おトク！５/６（金）まで**実施**　→　Customer appreciation!  All-you-can-drink drink bar, only ￥100 per person!  What a deal!  (Happening) Until May 6th