# Difference between 実践 and 実施

Tags: word-choice

I found 実践 in the context:

> 月を舞台に居住環境を構築し長期滞在を**実践**します

I had some difficulty to distinguish between **実践** and **実施**, so I checked a bit on the forum and found:

> 実施, on the other hand, refers generally to putting some plan into
>   action.

（Source: [What is the difference in usage of [実行]{じっこう}する and [実施]{じっし}する?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12306/what-is-the-difference-in-usage-of-%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%98%e3%81%a3%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-and-%e5%ae%9f%e6%96%bd%e3%81%98%e3%81%a3%e3%81%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)）

> 実践 is practice as opposed to theory. It's practice as in "bring it
>   into practice", "daily clinical practice", etc. It refers to actually
>   doing something instead of thinking or simulating. 実践的 means practical
>   as opposed to theoretical.

（Source: [What is the difference in meaning between 練習, 訓練 and 実践?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47916/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-%e7%b7%b4%e7%bf%92-%e8%a8%93%e7%b7%b4-and-%e5%ae%9f%e8%b7%b5)）

So I came to the conclusion that **実施** always refer to some kind of plan, policy, ... but not knowledge (put into practice what I have been taught)
you would use **実践** in that case.

Does it work like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For「実施」, the link you attached is almost fine to me as a source.

「実施」is "conduct"/"implementation"/"put into practice" things already planned in an organized manner.

> 「クールビズ実施の一環でノーネクタイで仕事をする。」: *"I work without wearing tie thanks to the implementation of [cool-biz campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_Biz_campaign)"*.

「実践」 is rather the actual personal action than the knowledge you merely have inside your head.

For example, when you are actually playing game such as shogi, soccer, mario-cart and whatever, you are using what you already have practiced, learned, and simulated how things going of games through guidebooks, instructors, observation or anything.

> いつも試合では練習で新しく教えてもらったことを即実践します。: *"I always immediately carry out new things in the game what I was taught during training."*